# Firebase database delete specific data by php

Tags: php, firebase

How can I remove firebase specific data? I use the
php `Kreait\Firebase` library.

```
  $fg = $database->getReference('raw_check_out')->orderByChild('reciptno')->equalTo($recipt)->getSnapshot();

  $reb = $fg->getValue();
  $fg->remove();
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Check this. `$database->getReference('raw_check_out')->orderByChild('reciptno')->equalTo($recipt)->getSnapshot()->remove();`

Comment: not working i already try this

Comment: did you try `delete()`?

Comment: What does „not working“ mean? Nothing happens? It is not deleted? You get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code example:

```
$fg = $database
    ->getReference('raw_check_out')
    ->orderByChild('reciptno')
    ->equalTo($recipt)
    ->getSnapshot();
```

Here `$fg` does not hold the reference, but the snapshot.

If you want to remove the reference after you have retrieved the data you need, you need the reference itself:

```
$fg = $database->getReference('raw_check_out');

$query = $fg->orderByChild('reciptno')->equalTo($recipt);
$reb = $query->getSnapshot()->getValue();

$fg->remove();
```

Comment: using this my tables all rows was deleted!!

Answer (score 0):

This function is for unsubscribing users if you want to remove "user-id-8776" and your structure is like:

[image]

```
public function unsubscribe($uid)
 {
    $ref = $this->database->getReference()->getChild('users')->getChild($uid)->orderByChild($uid)->getReference();
    $path = $ref->getUri()->getPath();
    $ref->remove();
 }
```

For any other data is more or less the same, you just have to find the reference of data you want to delete it and then you can remove it.

Comment: If `$uid` is an array of keys,what modification needed?

Comment: Please consider this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302397/needs-to-delete-firebase-db-node-using-multiple-keys-array-in-php

Comment: this removes all data

Answer (score 0):

Check Image

[image]

You have another option to resolve this problem. This solution given below:

```
    $url = "https://<projectID>.firebaseio.com/chatList/".<jsonFileName>."json";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```